# mysqli - Extract Column data into row fields ( need a query for this)

Tags: mysql

I want to convert some columns into rows. what is the best way? using mysqli and same table it self
Original data

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

OUTPUT

```
sort    id  name    Food1       Food2   Food3
1       P01 Sam     Ice Cream   Cake    Pizza
2       P02 pau     Burger      Fries   Egg
```

Expected Output

```
sort    id  name    Food1       
1       P01 Sam     Ice Cream       
2       P01 Sam     Cake        
3       P01 Sam     Pizza       
4       P02 pau     Burger      
5       P02 pau     Fries       
6       P02 pau     Egg
```

Comment: ----------------------------------------------- <br/>
SORT | id  | name | Food1     | Food2 | Food3<br/>
----------------------------------------------- <br/>
1    | P01 | Sam  | Ice Cream | Cake  | Pizza <br/>
----------------------------------------------- <br/>
2    | P02 | pau  | Burger    | Fries | Egg<br/>

Comment: 3 subqueries, each extracts one column, then UNION ALL.

Comment: What is the significance of the `sort` column and what is the logic behind it?